# Can not connect to mac build server in Visual studio (Xamarin forms)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

[image: Can not sign in to mac]

I can connect to the mac with ssh and when i try in VS it is found aswell. However this error is shown when i attempt to sign in.

Comment: Is anyone else experiencing this? It appeared yesterday. I have made sure to update VS, VS on the mac, XCode etc etc

Comment: Is remote login On in your Mac?

Comment: Yes. Login is fine as it works in simple ssh and authentication in VS is ok. Error comes after.

Comment: @AlexanderUddfeldt Reboot the Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this steps:

1, **Reboot** your device mac and windows.

2, When reboot, make sure that the Mac and windows **under the same network**.

3, Make sure that **Remote Login** is enabled on the Mac

4, If had added Mac before reboot, you should check the Mac's **IP** whether is changed when reboot.

More detail info,you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting). Or you can offer more info about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error in our networks. When sorted out this started to work as normal again. Sorry and thanks for all replies.